# How to split string in 3 pieces in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following code which split string in 2 pieces on the basis of space but I want to use this code to split the string in 3 pieces instead of two. is it possible ?

```
declare @strs nvarchar(max)

set @strs = 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Star, How I wounder what you are.'

set @strs = reverse(@strs)

select reverse(@strs) String,

reverse(right(@strs,len(@strs) - charindex(' ',@strs,30))) Description1,

ltrim(reverse(left(@strs,charindex(' ',@strs,30)))) Description2
```

Actually I have to copy data from table1 to table2. Table1 has field "**companyname**" which is varchar(120). But the table2 has 3 fields each is varchar(40)"**companyname1**", "**companyname2**","**companyname3**". I need to split the string in 3 pieces but in a logical way, on the basis of space and with a limit of 40 characters.

E.g if a string is "**Alufinish Gesellschaft für Verfahrenstechnik u. zur Metalloberflächenbehandlung mbH & C**"

it should split like this on the basis of space

"**Alufinish Gesellschaft für**"
"**Verfahrenstechnik u. zur **" 
"**Metalloberflächenbehandlung mbH & C**"

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Comment: actually I have to copy data from table1 to table2. Table1 has field "companyname" which is varchar(120). But the table2 has 3 fields each is varchar(40)"companyname1", "companyname2","companyname3". So that why I need to split the string in 3 pieces but in a logical way on the basis of space and with a limit of 40 characters. E.g if a string is "LEP Loll Entlackungs- u. Pulverbeschichtungsgesellschaft mbH" it should split like this "LEP Loll Entlackungs-" , "u. Pulverbeschichtungsgesellschaft", "mbH"

Comment: This is dangerous...Take for instance an example that the initial companyname has a length of exactly 120. Then the resulted strings should be of length exactly 40, or else the insertion would fail. You would have to be lucky to have the space exactly at 41st and 81st characters.

Comment: @user2906622 Please update your question with additional details. Don't write them in comments.

Comment: There is some code here to split a string into rows, maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852612/split-string-in-sql-server-to-a-maximum-length-returning-each-as-a-row

Comment: You have spaces in the company name and spaces between company names. How can you know what space to use for the split?

Comment: the space after 39 characters but not split in a not logical manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little "brute force" approach.. Perhaps you should encapsulate in a function, and definitely you need to control if there are less than three words in the string, but this should work.

```
declare @strs nvarchar(max)

set @strs = 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Star, How I wonder what you are. High above noseque sky high'
declare @lon int
declare @palabras int
declare @contador int
declare @posicion int
declare @string1 varchar(max)
declare @string2 varchar(max)
declare @string3 varchar(max)

--wordcount
set @palabras = LEN(@strs)-LEN(replace(@strs, ' ', ''))+1
--words per batch
set @lon = @palabras/3
set @contador = 1
set @posicion = 0
while @contador <= @lon
begin
-- search for the first batch
    set @posicion = CHARINDEX(' ',@strs,@posicion+1)
    set @contador = @contador+1
end 
set @string1 = LEFT(@strs, @posicion)
set @strs = replace(@strs, @string1, '')

set @contador = 1
set @posicion = 0
while @contador <= @lon
begin
-- search for the second batch
    set @posicion = CHARINDEX(' ',@strs,@posicion+1)
    set @contador = @contador+1
end 
set @string2 = LEFT(@strs, @posicion)
set @string3 = replace(@strs, @string2, '')

select @string1, @string2, @string3
```

Comment: How do I control if there are less than 3 words. I have alot of strings with only one word.

Comment: In the first lines I define the wordcount in *palabras*. If its two you should get only *string1* and *string2* (as *string3* will be empty) if its one then *strs* is your only piece of string