# Add a '-' in a varchar SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to transform some strings from this format:

```
"1020202020"
```

To

```
"1-0-2-0-2-0-2-0-2-0"
```

How can I do that in a simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every day I wake up and think to myself "What impossible thing will CTEs make possible today?"

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        '1020202020' inputstring,
        convert(varchar(max),'') outputstring
    union all
    select
        substring(inputstring,2,len(inputstring)),
        outputstring + left(inputstring,1) + '-' + case when len(inputstring) = 2 then right(inputstring,1) else '' end
    from cte
    where len(inputstring) > 1
)
select top 1 outputstring from cte order by len(outputstring) desc
```

Comment: Accepted 10 seconds after it was posted??

Comment: Made a small adjustment. Didn't need the 'X' padding the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear on the exact rules are for the placement of the hyphens.
So, there might be some clever method using `replace()`.

For your example string:

```
select replace(replace(col, '02', '-0-2'), '20', '2-0')
```

Comment: Actually i thought it was simple as _put a hyphen between all characters_. I guess [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079259/284240) should work(with 1 as parameter) combined with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170551/284240). However, the last hyphen must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed like this :

```
TRIM(TRAILING "-" FROM REPLACE("10203040", "0", "-0-"))
```

Comment: What makes you think there's anything special about the zeros?

Comment: well the question says: "... this format: 1020202020 ..."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-loop/non-recursive solution. I had some fun with REPLACE() and it's VERY efficient. It can process 100,000 rows in less than a second which is probably better than any looping or recursive solution.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('strings') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE strings;

CREATE TABLE strings (string BIGINT);

--Populate the table
WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM strings) < 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO strings
        SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL
        SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL
        SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL
        SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL
        SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000 UNION ALL SELECT RAND() * 10000000000
END

--Add the hyphens with REPLACE() and cut off the extra hyphen at the end with SUBSTRING()
SELECT SUBSTRING(
                REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(string, '0', '0-'),'1','1-'),'2','2-'),'3','3-'),'4','4-'),'5','5-'),'6','6-'),'7','7-'),'8','8-'),'9','9-'),
                0,
                LEN(string)*2
                ) AS String
FROM strings;
```

Abbreviated Results:

```
String
------------------------
5-6-1-2-9-4-9-0-8-1
7-5-8-5-1-9-3-0-9
2-2-4-7-6-1-5-7-6-9
9-3-4-6-1-0-3-5-0
9-9-5-3-6-8-8-7-8-9
5-3-7-2-0-5-3-0-6
8-4-0-8-9-8-9-4-5-0
9-8-6-4-6-8-4-4-3-9
6-6-5-8-2-8-7-3-9-2
...
```